# Matplotlib animations - how to export them to a format to use in a presentation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

So, I learned how to make cute little animations in matplotlib. For example, this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure() 
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111) 

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)

dt = 0.01
q  = 0.01
t = np.arange(0,1,dt)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t,x, '-')
fig.canvas.draw()
for i in xrange(100):
    x = (1-q) * x + q* np.random.normal(size = len(t))
    line.set_ydata(x)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

This works and it's very nice.  But how I use this to make a movie I can display, for example, in a pdf presentation? I tried to do `fig.savefig("test.gif")` but there's an error message indicating that matplotlib doesn't export gifs.

Is there a way of doing this without resorting to external tools (like making a lot of png's and stitching them together)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, no there is no other way besides using an external tool. There is a new module in 1.1.0 that helps you do [animations](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html#animation) and save them to mpeg4 format. It uses an external tool to automatically do this conversion, from many frames to a single movie. You can make your gif using [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s convert or use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), which are the two options provided by the new animation module.

Comment: +1. However, you probably mean mencoder instead of memcoder, right?

Comment: Right, so I just add a `fig.savefig("foo%d.png"%i)` to save each frame and use mencoder?

Comment: Exactly. This is what the new animation module does. If you don't want to use the module, call mencoder from python and then you can unlink the foo*png files afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `matplotlib.animation` and have something like `FFmpeg` in your path then this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation

fig = plt.figure() 
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111) 

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)

dt = 0.01
q  = 0.01
t = np.arange(0,1,dt)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
images = []

for i in xrange(100):
    x = (1-q) * x + q* np.random.normal(size = len(t))
    line, = ax.plot(t,x, '-')
    images.append((line,))

line_anim = ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=50, blit=True)
line_anim.save('my_animation.mp4')
plt.show()
```

cute, eh?

Comment: Indeed! Is there a way to set the framerate of the output mp4? @danodonovan

Comment: If you change the `interval` parameter in the `ArtistAnimation` it should change the framerate. There's probably an `FFmpeg` variable too, but I'm not `FFmpeg` expert.

Comment: Thanks! This is quite helpful.