# Saving matplotlib figure from tkinter application without using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am using multiple `matplotlib` figures to visualize data in a `tkinter` application and so far that has been going great by using the [explicit interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html), i.e. by working on the axis objects.

Now I would like to save some figures to files. For this I can only find the pyplot function `plt.savefig` which is using the `pyplot` interface. Hence, since I have multiple figures I need to run

```
plt.figure(somefig)
```

to choose the figure I'd like to save. Unfortunately, this breaks in my usecase since I'm using `FigureCanvasTkAgg` to get the canvas for `tkinter`. As discribed in [this bugreport](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19380), that call ruins the figure mangager so the call `plt.figure(somefig)` results in the error

```
ValueError: The passed figure is not managed by pyplot
```

So I guess my question is: Is there a way to save a figure witout using the implicit `pyplot` module?

Comment: Have you tried all of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9886274/13629335) ?

Comment: Indeed I have, and for various reasons they are all not an option. And even if so, I feel like there should be a more direct way without going the detour over canvas and potentially even temporary files. After all, matplotlib does have the functionality already build in

Comment: So you are asking for a matplot inherent solution? I think you should update your question then, to be more exact about what you looking for.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21464691/13629335) does not use `savefig`. Is that what you are looking for ? And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391026/13629335) are some alternatives.

Comment: Ah, yes, `print_png` from you second link was what I was looking for. That bypasses `savefig` and works directly on the figure object. If you would like to post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept that.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable to copy and paste another ones answer and get rewarded for. I'd rather mark it as duplicate or would suggest you to post it yourself as answer with a link to the original author. But thank you for the offer, glad I could help.